# how to run a polymer app via "Run in Dartium" from console?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to call a polymer webapp directly via command line or via 'Process' in a dart file.

I know when running it via the dart editor, a server on port 8080 is created and listening to requests for the /web folder.

but when launching

dartium/chrome.exe path/To/Index.html

from console its simply loading the files inside the browser but wont start a server for the client.

via 
file:://path/to/file.html [no 'dart is not runnning' warning, but no polymer content]
or
127.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x:xxxxxxxx/app/index.html will obviously tell me

'This webpage is not available'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this script as an example `how to call a polymer webapp directly via 'Process' in a dart file`.

This example also includes launch of default browser.

```dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:io";
import "package:path/path.dart" as pathos;

void main(List<String> args) {
  String app;
  String file;
  switch (args.length) {
    case 1:
      app = args[0];
      break;
    case 2:
      app = args[0];
      file = args[1];
      break;
    default:
      print("Usage: pubserve.dart app_path [file_name]");
      exit(0);
  }

  if(!new Directory(app).existsSync()) {
    print("Directory not exists: $app");
    exit(-1);
  }

  pubServe(app, file).then((exitCode) {
    exit(exitCode);
  });
}

Future<int> pubServe(String app, String file) {
  var sdk = Platform.environment["DART_SDK"];
  if (sdk == null) {
    print("Dart SDK not found");
    return new Future(() => -1);
  }

  var executable = pathos.join(sdk, "bin", "pub");
  var pattern = r"^Serving (?:.*) web on (.*)$";
  var regexp = new RegExp(pattern);
  return Process.start(executable, ["serve"], runInShell: true,
      workingDirectory: app).then((process) {
    process.stdout.listen((data) {
      var string = new String.fromCharCodes(data);
      for (var c in data) {
        stdout.writeCharCode(c);
      }

      var match = regexp.matchAsPrefix(string);
      if (match != null) {
        var url = match.group(1);
        if (file != null) {
          url += "/$file";
        }

        Timer.run(() => runBrowser(url));
      }
    });

    process.stderr.pipe(stderr);
    stdin.pipe(process.stdin);
    return process.exitCode.then((exitCode) {
      return exitCode;
    });
  });
}

void runBrowser(String url) {
  var fail = false;
  switch (Platform.operatingSystem) {
    case "linux":
      Process.run("x-www-browser", [url]);
      break;
    case "macos":
      Process.run("open", [url]);
      break;
    case "windows":
      Process.run("explorer", [url]);
      break;
    default:
      fail = true;
      break;
  }

  if (!fail) {
    //print("Start browsing...");
  }
}
```

P.S.

**NOTE:**

If you run this script from Dart Editor, Editor will never stops execution of subprocess (`pub serve` in our case) when you stop current script in Dart Editor.

This is not related only to this script. Editor always keep subprocesses alive.

If you run it from cmd-line it terminates `pub serve` correctly.

Comment: I have not tried the code jet, so this example is for "Run in Dartium" or "Run as JavaScript" since you use default browser. Where and how would you specify that

Comment: @H.R. It is a command line script for `launch polymer web app via pub serve`. It can be used as a global script for launch any `polymer web app` from any directory. Example (for Windows users): `%DART_SDK%\bin\dart pubserve.dart c:\users\user\dart\polymer_app01 polymer_app01.html`. Also it can be embedded in your own web app launcher (command line).

Comment: I mean is it generating js code? or working with the dart code, since in runBrowsers you use explorer, not dartium. or does pub serve do magic to serve both? didnt think so

Comment: @H.R. One of task that it performs is (in my sample) `Compiling polymer_app01|web/polymer_app01.html_bootstrap.dart...`. This is a `pub` task. You can wrote basic polymer app and try launch it via this script and see result as console output. This means that web app can be executed in any browser.

Answer (score 5):

DartEditor lauches `pub serve`. You can do this manually without Darteditor (since Dart 1.5 AFAIK). Just launch

```
pub serve
```

from within your Polymer app package directory.
Inside your console app launch the browser with the URL that loads the page from this server.

You could also include web server functionality into your console application that serves the Polymer app to your browser.

```
pub help serve
```

lists the available options.